# Unity3D 2D Simple Flight Physics

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, physics

I want to create a simple flight physics sim, arcade-y like game, in 2D.
I don't want something too realistic, just something fun.

Unfortunately, my code leads to a game, where my plane acts more like a missile in space, than an aerodynamic plane.

I've checked for questions around the internet, the closest one I found was [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity2D/comments/4bes4g/noob_question_how_to_2d_realistic_flight_physics/).
Which the guy wrote about this [game](http://runway.countlessprojects.com/prototype/index.html).

The game looks a bit like what I want to do.

I couldn't find any **practical** code I can use to make my plane more realistic, so I'm looking for help.

**Please**, do not send me to learn aerodynamics or to something not useful, I do have a simple understanding, and I would like some practical help, not theoretical one.

The main issue I have, is when I want to pitch up/down the plane, the plane just rotates itself with the Torque force, however, it doesn't change it's direction quickly with the air flow (since there's no 'real' air flow...)
I've tried playing with the rigidbody drag, and angular drag, and the parameters, I've added a drag force of my own... I am missing something and I don't know what. I was also looking at [these formulas](http://www.aerostudents.com/courses/intro-to-aerospace-1/aerodynamics-and-aircraft-limits.pdf), I didn't find the solution.

Thanks in advance,

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlaneController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float thrustFactor = 0.01f;
    public float maxThrustFactor = 1.0f;
    public float liftFactor = 0.1f;
    public float turnFactor = 0.1f;
    public float gravityFactor = 0.1f;
    public float dragFactor = 0.1f;

    public float thrust;
    public float liftForce;
    private Vector2 planeVelocity;
    private Rigidbody2D transformRigidbody;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        thrust = 0;
        liftForce = 0;
        transformRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        planeVelocity = transformRigidbody.velocity;

        PlaneGravity();
        PlaneThrust();
        PlaneDrag();
        PlaneTurn();
        PlaneLift();
    }

    void PlaneLift()
    {
        float attackAngle = transform.eulerAngles.z;
        if ((attackAngle > 0 && attackAngle <= 45) || (attackAngle > 90 && attackAngle <= 135))
            liftForce = Mathf.Sin(attackAngle) * liftFactor * planeVelocity.sqrMagnitude;
        else if ((attackAngle > 45 && attackAngle <= 90) || (attackAngle > 135 && attackAngle <= 180))
            liftForce = Mathf.Cos(attackAngle) * liftFactor * planeVelocity.sqrMagnitude;

        transformRigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * Mathf.Abs(liftForce) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    void PlaneThrust()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            thrust += thrustFactor;
            thrust = Mathf.Min(thrust, maxThrustFactor);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            thrust -= thrustFactor;
            thrust = Mathf.Max(0, thrust);
        }

        transformRigidbody.AddForce(transform.right * thrust * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    void PlaneGravity()
    {
        transformRigidbody.AddForce(gravityFactor * Vector2.down * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    void PlaneDrag()
    {
        transformRigidbody.AddForce(-transform.right * planeVelocity.sqrMagnitude * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    void PlaneTurn()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("up"))
        {
            transformRigidbody.AddTorque(-turnFactor * Mathf.Abs(planeVelocity.sqrMagnitude) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("down"))
        {
            transformRigidbody.AddTorque(turnFactor * Mathf.Abs(planeVelocity.sqrMagnitude) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;

        if (other.name == "LeftCollider")
        {
            newPosition.x += 17;
        }

        if (other.name == "RightCollider")
        {
            newPosition.x -= 17;
        }

        transform.SetPositionAndRotation(newPosition, transform.rotation);
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.transform.name == "Ground")
        {
            transformRigidbody.freezeRotation = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagine your plane is flying to the right at max speed one frame and then is flying up the next game (this is a hyperbolic example, but shows where the problem is). How does the drag function apply to this case?

Comment: @Draco18s the gravity would affect it in the Y axis. I also tried adding the rigidbody basic physics... I don't know what's missing or how to implement it

Comment: Ignore gravity right now, gravity pulls the plane down and we want a plane flying up to lose *horizontal* motion...via drag. Look at the drag function and figure out why it does not impart horizontal forces on a plane facing directly up.

Comment: Oh you're right, forgot to add the drag factor in the function.